# Limit Problem Involving Number Sets

Tags: limits

Let $\mathbb{N} = \left\{ 1, 2, 3, ... \right\}$.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_n$ be a finite set of real numbers.

Assume $\forall m, n \in \mathbb{N}, ~m \neq n \Rightarrow A_m \cap A_n = \emptyset~$.

Assume $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}, (\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in A_n) \wedge 0 < |x - 7| < \varepsilon$.

I can tell that as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0,~ x \rightarrow 7$.

Since this predicate can satisfy any $\varepsilon > 0$, there are an infinite number of elements $x$ that approach 7 but never reach 7.

Since all the sets are finite, the only way $x \rightarrow 7$ is if $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $x \in A_n$.

But so far, I can't prove this formally.

How do I prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 7} \! ~n = \infty$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_N$ denote the element of $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N A_i$ closest to (but not equal<sup>[1]</sup>) $7$, and $\varepsilon_N = |x_N - 7|$.

Then for any $\varepsilon \in (0, \varepsilon_N)$ there is no $x$ in first $N$ sets which differs less than by $\varepsilon$ from $7$.

In other words, one must take more and more $A_i$ sets to find better and better approximation of $7$ in them.

---

Note 1. See [the comment by Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755990/limit-problem-involving-number-sets/3756010#comment7725940_3756010).

Comment: This isn’t quite right: the element of $\bigcup_{i=1}^NA_i$ closest to $7$ may be $7$. The hypotheses do not exclude the possibility that $7$ belongs to some $A_i$; that’s why $x$ is required to satisfy $0<|x-7|$ as well as $|x-7|<\epsilon$ in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're right. Fixed. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is an $\epsilon_n>0$ such that $$(7-\epsilon_n,7+\epsilon_n)\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^n(A_k\setminus\{7\})=\varnothing\;.$$